# How do write this type shortcode?

Tags: shortcode

How do I write this shortcode or any alternative?

```
echo do_shortcode ('[gviewer file="$att_url"]');
```

Any suggestions someone?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? What does the shortcode do?

Comment: Please stop posting the same question under two different profiles

Answer (score 1):

You can use below shortcode ..

```
$att_url  is document path 
<?php echo do_shortcode('[gview file="'.$att_url.'"]');   ?>
```